# Calculating time using SUVAT equations with unknown initial velocity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

I understand that the equation used to find the equation used to find displacement when the initial velocity is unknown is:

$vt-(at^2)/2$

how would you rearrange this to solve for $t\;?$ When I try I get $t$ on both sides of the equation.

Comment: [Quadratic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) maybe?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "when the initial velocity is known"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rearrange using the quadratic formula to get:
$$
t = \frac{-u±\sqrt(u^2+2as)}{a}
$$
Thanks AccidentalFourierTransform for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The equation used to find the displacement in motion with constant acceleration in 1 dimension is -

$ s = ut + \frac{a{t}^{2}}{2} $

where u is the initial velocity , s is displacement and a is acceleration (constant).

You can re-write the equation as -

$ t^2 + \frac{2u}{a}t - \frac{2s}{a} = 0 $

or $ (t + \frac{u}{a})^2 - \frac{2s}{a} - \frac{u^2}{a^2} = 0 $

$ (t + \frac{u}{a})^2 =  \frac{u^2 + 2sa}{a^2}  $

$ t + \frac{u}{a} =  \pm\frac{\sqrt{u^2 + 2sa}}{|a|}  $

So, $ t  =  - \frac{u}{a} \pm\frac{\sqrt{u^2 + 2sa}}{|a|}  $

(You can get the same result by using the quadratic formula.)

Comment: The OP specified that $u$, the initial velocity is unknown...